# Ok to bring in small, cut and dried flowers and leaves, and small stones, into the USA?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Long ago I visited my ancestral village in Greece, and while there, saved some small wildflowers and leaves in my diary. I also took some small, colorful stones from the Ionian sea. Today, looking through my old diary and seeing these precious little momentos, it occured to me that bringing in these several small flowers and leaves (and stones) might have been a no-no--though it never seems wrong back then! I always thought of plants and fruits that were restricted as fresh fruits, or live plants. Am I ok to have done this?

Comment: You will find an answer to your question at [CBP INFO Center Home: Find an Answer](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/list/noIntercept/1)

Comment: actually, I already looked there and found no answer to my specific question. Would appreciate anyone who can answer my question responding.

Answer (score 6):

You can bring the flowers and stones ***to*** the United States but you must **declare** them to Customs for Agriculture inspection.

[Bringing Agricultural Products Into the United States](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/clearing-cbp/bringing-agricultural-products-united-states)

If the Agriculture Officer allows them, you're good to go.  If not, they will be seized and destroyed, but *you will not be fined* or suffer any other consequences because you declared them.

People get in trouble for smuggling.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I ok to have done this?

Nobody except CBP can tell you definitively.

U.S. Customs and Border Protection:
[Specialty/seasonal/holiday food and plant items](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1157/kw/flowers)

> In passenger baggage, **every fruit or vegetable as well as every meat
> or poultry product must be declared to a CBP Agriculture Specialist or
> CBP Officer and must be presented for inspection** - regardless of its
> admissibility status.
>
> Fruits and Vegetables: Travelers may check the general admissibility
> of fruits and vegetables by consulting APHIS's FAVIR database at
> http://www.aphis.usda.gov/favir/. Simply select the type of fruit or
> vegetable in

Comment: The FAVIR link is a dead link. Updated information can be found here: [Don't Pack a Pest](https://www.dontpackapest.com/).